# How to send a response from a method that is not the controller method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've got a `Controller.php` whose `show($id)` method is hit by a route.

```
public function show($id)
{
    // fetch a couple attributes from the request ...

    $this->checkEverythingIsOk($attributes);

    // ... return the requested resource.
    return $response;
}
```

Now, in `checkEverythingIsOk()`, I perform some validation and authorization stuff. These checks are common to several routes within the same controller, so I'd like to extract these checks and call the method everytime I need to perform the same operations.

The problem is, I'm unable to send some responses from this method:

```
private function checkEverythingIsOk($attributes)
{
    if (checkSomething()) {
        return response()->json('Something went wrong'); // this does not work - it will return, but the response won't be sent.
    }

    // more checks...
    return response()->callAResponseMacro('Something else went wrong'); // does not work either.

    dd($attributes); // this works.
    abort(422); // this works too.
}
```

*Note:* Yes, I know in general one can use middleware or validation services to perform the checks before the request hits the controller, but I don't want to. I need to do it this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably looking for this:

```
function checkEverythingIsOk() {
    if (checkSomething()) {
        return Response::json('Something went wrong');
    }
    if(checkSomethingElse()) {
        return Response::someMacro('Something else is wrong')
    }
    return null; // all is fine
}
```

And in the controller method:

```
$response = $this->checkEverythingIsOk();
if($response !== null) { // $response instanceof Response
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: The error message response format is not the same with every error type. Sometimes I'll want to call a response macro which will fetch other data from the database, other times I'll simply print a message, abort, etc...

Comment: How about `return $this->checkEverythingIsOk($attributes);` ? `dd()` and `abort()` will cancel script execution anyways. You can return `null` if everything is ok, and the response if not, then do a simple check in the controller method.

Comment: This is the correct answer for PHP in general, but Boris D. Teoharov has a better answer for laravel specifically by using the `->send()` method of response.

Answer (score 24):

As of Laravel 5.6 you can now use for example `response()->json([1])->send();`.

There is no need for it to be the return value of a controller method.

Note that calling `send()` will not terminate the output. You may want to call `exit;` manually after `send()`.

Comment: If you use sonarqube analysis, it will raise issues for multiple returns (more than 3). With this method that can be override.

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) Thanks! This allows us to implement the guard pattern (where validator is not enough), like: `$myDependency = $this->guardMyDependency($request);`

Answer (score 7):

It's probably overkill, but I will throw it in anyway. You might want to look into internal requests. Also this is just pseudoish code, I have not actually done this, so take this bit of information with caution.

```
// build a new request
$returnEarly = Request::create('/returnearly');

// dispatch the new request
app()->handle($newRequest);

// have a route set up to catch those
Route::get('/returnearly', ...);
```

Now you can have a Controller sitting at the end of that route and interpret the parameters, or you use multiple routes answered by multiple Controllers/Methods ... up to you, but the approach stays the same.

UPDATE

Ok I just tried that myself, creating a new request and dispatching that, it works this way. Problem is, the execution does not stop after the child-request has exited. It goes on in the parent request. Which makes this whole approach kind of useless.

But I was thinking about another way, why not throw an Exception and catch it in an appropriate place to return a specified response?

Turns out, thats already built into Laravel:

```
// create intended Response
$response = Response::create(''); // or use the response() helper

// throw it, it is a Illuminate\Http\Exception\HttpResponseException
$response->throwResponse();
```

Now usually an Exception would be logged and you if you are in Debug mode, you would see it on screen etc. etc. But if you take a look into `\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler` within the `render` method you can see that it inspects the thrown Exception if it is an instance of `HttpResponseException`. If it is then the Response will be returned immediately.

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to work around this, but your approach is essentially the same as @Vojo123, albeit catching an exception instead of null-checking, with the added complexity of creating and handling the internal request. If you look at the Laravel API docs, one realizes there is no way of sending a full-blown request from a method other than the controller method, so these two workarounds are as good as it is going to get.

Comment: The internal request part doesn't work anyway. Just ignore that. The thrown Response is a solution on its own, you can also write it in one line, like response(...)->throwResponse(); As the catching is already built into Laravel one might even argue, that its not a workaround but actually the intended use case.

Answer (score 7):

To me the most simple and elegant way is:

```php
response()->json($messages_array, $status_code)->throwResponse();
```

(you don`t need return)

It can be called from a private function or another class...

I use this in a helper class to check for permissions, and if the user doesn`t have it I throw with the above code.